# How does insertion order affect output inserted value?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I understand from various sources on the internet that the following sql:

```
insert into mainTable(status)
output inserted.mainid into tmpTable(TARGET_ID)
select '0' from impTable
order by impid asc;
```

doesn't guarantee that the rows will be inserted in the mainTable in the order specified by the 'order by' in the select statement, although the values in the mainTable identity column (mainid) will be in the correct sequence.

My question is how this affects the inserted.mainid that is output into the tmpTable.
Will they be added to the tmpTable in the order rows are inserted in the mainTable or will they folllow the sequence of the generated mainid identity values?

Nevermind the usefulness of the SQL, it's a technical question.

**EDIT:** Fixed the column missmatch in the SQL example

Comment: its all moot, when you `SELECT` from a table the order of results is undefined unless you specify an `ORDER BY`, they just generally happen to be returned in the order of the clustered index for simple queries, since that is the fastest way for the engine to satisfy your request.

Comment: But there is an `ORDER BY` in the example, or am I missing something?

Comment: To answer your question more, we need to now how mainId is generated?

Comment: You don't show how you extract any results from `tmpTable`, thats why the question is moot.

Comment: Mainid is an autoincremented identity column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to know the order.

If you look at this page from MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) you will find the following statement:

"There is no guarantee that the order in which the changes are applied to the table and the order in which the rows are inserted into the output table or table variable will correspond."

Answer (score 2):

As you state in your comment `mainid` is an `IDENTITY` column, its value will increase monotonically but, since the value you are inserting are not from `impTable` I don't see how this matters.

Each new `mainId` will get inserted into `tmpTable`. The data will be stored in the order of the clutsered index of `tmpTable`, if `tmpTable` has no clustered index, then the order is undefined. This doesn't matter either way, except for performance reasons. When you select data from `tmpTable` the order of results wil be undefined unless you specify an `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Yes, there was a typo regarding the columns in the SQL. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter what order rows are stored in the table because you **can't observe** that order. When selecting without `order by` the order is undefined and does not necessarily conform to stored order. The stored order is meaningless for that reason.

There is no way to say "give me all rows in stored order". All you can say is "return them in any order" or "return them in this exact order".

Comment: If your `ORDER BY` is the same as the clustered index then you are garaunteed to get the rows in stored order. However, this may not be related to the order of insertion. If the table is a HEAP, i.e. no clustered index, then there is no relationship.

Comment: True. The relationship is *always* coincidental. Column Store indexes don't even *have* a stored order!